# R - Tokenization - single and two letter words in a TermDocumentMatrix

Tags: r, nlp, tokenize, tm

I am currently trying to do a little bit of text processing and I would like to get the one and two letter words in a TermDocumentMatrix.

The issue is that it seems to display only 3 letter words and more.

```
    library(tm)
    library(RWeka)

    test<-'This is a test.'

    testmyCorpus<-Corpus(VectorSource(test))
    testTDF<-TermDocumentMatrix(testmyCorpus, control=list(tokenize=AlphabeticTokenizer))
    inspect(testTDF)
```

Only the words "this" and "test" are displayed. Any ideas?

Thanks a lot for you help!
Robert

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24388735/4588780) is the answer to almost your problem: in short, you should add an option `control=list(wordLengths=c(1,Inf)` to TermDocumentMatrix.

Comment: Hi @Robert if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.